# Python: recognising integers in a list with groupby intertool

Tags: python, list

I'm quite new to Python, I've been trying to use groupby to recognise integers in a list but don't know what to use as a key.

I've tried to use `group = groupby (mylist, key = isinstance(int))`

But I'm confused about what should I use as the first parameter of isinstance().

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lambda k: isinstance(k, int)` as key function:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [0, 1, 3, 6, 'art', 'xxx', 55, 54]


for v, g in groupby(a, lambda k: isinstance(k, int)):
    print(list(g))
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6]
['art', 'xxx']
[55, 54]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej, this works perfectly, honestly I didn't even know about the existence of lambda functions till know, I apologize in case this was a foolish question.